# Best way to sell cheap/damaged bike

Tags: cruiser

I have an old cruiser bike that I paid $100 for. The tire popped and the other has a flat but other than that it's ridable. Any way I can sell it? And if so, best website/company to sell it to?

Comment: http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites

I sold an old roomates bike for $20 on craigslist. It had a flat timre, needed a new seat & had been left outside in the desert for a year. For the right price, there is someone to buy just about anything...

Comment: Craigslist or a local equivalent.  Sometimes the ad board at a supermarket will get good response.

Comment: A bike like that is probably worth half if the tires are flat. Fixing them is a good Idea before trying to sell it.

Comment: @BSOrider  One tire and two tubes is $30 minimum.  Are you sure the bike will sell for $60 with two good tires.

Comment: Another thing to consider is a bike co-op or some other agency that fixes up bikes for the indigent.  They may fix it up or may scrap it for parts, but they will put it to best use.  Of course, you'd get nothing for it but maybe a small tax write-off.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misunderstood something: when you say "the tire popped", do you mean that the tire literally broke (not just the tube)?

Comment: Even if the tire has to be replaced, it will not cost the world, if going for a cheap tire, or better, find one laying around in own or friends shed.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a note on the local message board, like the one in the school or the local supermarket, or the online version like Craiglist.
Most likely you will not get anything if people have to pay for transport, selling really local might be the best option.

But fixing the tires and cleaning it up might double the money you can get.

An other option is to keep it for when you can get a discount on a new bike on handing in an old one. Not sure that one comes around when you have a bike to get off your hands, but when there is one it will bring more for your bike than any private sale of an old bike.

Comment: Double the money does not mean recover the cost.

Comment: "Tire popped and the other has a flat".  Tire is not free and neither is a patch.  Even if the patch is $1 it takes time and it may fail.

Comment: Really have to know how to patch a tire to participate on this site?  If the OP had spare tire or access to used at $5 and could patch you think they would be posting that question?